# Making a changing text ex. Making an every day video clip about weather

Tags: text, after-effects

We recently we bought a led screen(About 8x3 mts) and it allows us to publish videos from AE (obviusly). We need to design a goodweel campaign about weather, traffic, and breaking news.

My quesion is how can i replace the animated text and images without modifyng the AE original file?, for example: The weather is sunny and 27 celsius, the next day weather changes and i just have to modify a txt.(something like that), and I just have to export the avi. file and be ready to upload it to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think After Effects is an appropriate solution for this. You would have to re-render your movie every time the weather changes. That would be some heavy CPU usage just to update the news or weather.  You might want to look into programming something that would update itself and using After Effects simply to render the media assets that would make up your program.

Maybe researching something like JavaScript or [Processing](http://processing.org) would be beneficial.